# Combining two list columns into one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a two columns made up of lists of different sizes. I want to join these columns into one and have the lists combined. So if the first row has a list like this [0, 1, 2] and the other one is this [3, 2], I want the first row of my new column to be [0, 1, 2, 3, 2].

I have a solution using an apply, but that takes way too long considering I have 7 million lines. I want to use numpy. Here is the code for apply :

df.apply(lambda x : np.concatenate((x["genres"], x["Certificate"])), axis = 1)

My numpy code looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzFkA.png). Even though I do like described on this website : https://ioflood.com/blog/numpy-concatenate/ it is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I don't have much hair left to pull out.

Comment: Please don't use images of code/data, provide a [mre]. Do you have lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: looks like it's working, but just not producing what you want.